# Ошибка в Intent при повороте экрана перед нажатием на пункт списка. Attempt to invoke virtual method 'getPackageName()' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragment, android-intent

Hе могу понять причину появления ошибки в Intent. Есть Item который по клику открывaет NextActivity. Но если перед нажатием на элемент списка перевернуть экран то при нажатии появляется ошибка:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference.

Проект написан по mvvm.

```
private ProjectsAdapter.OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener = username -> {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),ProfileActivity.class);//ошибка указывет на эту строку
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ProfileFragment.PROFILE_KEY, username);
        intent.putExtra(ProfileActivity.USERNAME_KEY, args);
        startActivity(intent);
    };
```

Если не переворачивать экран то все нормально работает. В чем может быть причина ?

Comment: `getActivity()` возвращает `null` - надо разобраться почему. Чей это метод вообще-то (какому классу принадлежит)?

Comment: Было бы круто, если бы ты еще приложил немного xml разметки той активности, на которой лежал список. Потому что в зависимости от того, что у тебя там и еще какие права есть у приложения (конкретно изменение конфигурации) эта ситуация будет протекать по разным сценариям. А пока попробуй использовать не `getActivity()` а `YourActivityName.this`

Comment: @woesss это в ProjectsFragment https://github.com/ihorkozar/beahance_mvvm)

Comment: @Dehedero это в ProjectsFragment github.com/ihorkozar/beahance_mvvm